# Finding a vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

Give a formula $F=M(x,y)i + N(x,y)j$ for the vector field in the plane that has the property that F points toward the origin with magnitude inversely proportional to the square of the distance from (x,y) to the origin. (The field is not defined at (0,0)).

I first found the norm of the vector $|F|=k/(x^2+y^2)$ with k>0.

Then I set $F=|F|n$ with n being the direction of the vector F. I put $n=(-x)i+(-y)j$ but the solution manual set $n=(-x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})i+(-y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})j$ and I don't understand why.

Comment: Because they probably want $n$ to be an unit vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n$ should be so that $||n||= 1$

Comment: Why is that? Isn't n just the direction?

Comment: because $||F|| = ||F|| ||n||$  so $||n||$ must be $1$

Comment: I see, so what are the consequences of using $n=(-x)i+(-y)j$, isn't it the same direction?

Comment: This is the right direction but you can't use this vector as the equality $F=|F|n$ wouldn't hold

Comment: So a vector equality is Vector=Magnitude*UnitVectorDirection ?

Comment: You got it ! Well done :)